# Як перекласти українською: "Одно дело, когда"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно перекласти російський вираз: "Одно дело, когда ..., и совсем другое, когда ..."?

[GRAC](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first_form) чомусь не показує жодних результатів, коли я пишу: "Одне діло, коли" або "Одна справа, коли."

Comment: Мабуть, проблема в тому, що Ви неправильно шукали. Я не зовсім тямлю, як правильно шукати в «ГРАК» фрагменти з розділовими знаками, але коли я шукаю з комою й пробілом після неї, то мені нічого не знаходить, а коли я шукаю з комою й пробілами з обох боків від неї, то знаходить.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У «ГРАК» я, загалом, бачу:

- і «[одна справа](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac6&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22[%D0%9E%D0%BE]%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%22+%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%22) <…>, а інша <…>»:

  > Одна справа — взяти готове, а друга — їхати за цим самому, їхати в далекий степ, де можна зіткнутися з якимсь татарським загоном і попасти в сирівці, — це не проста справа. // Андрій Чайковський, «На уходах», 1921.
- і «[одна річ](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac6&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22[%D0%9E%D0%BE]%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%22+%22%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%22) <…>, а інша <…>»:

  > Я знаю, що воно природно, конечно, — знаю, однако, що ти пристала би в разі конечності на всяке життя, — але бажання — одна річ, а конечність друга. // Іван Франко, лист, 1879.
  >
  > Але одна річ вирозуміти факт і його причину і друга — жити під тиском цього факту. // Олександр Кониський, «Думки і помітки», 1885.
  >
  > Одначе, тут, на сході, сила афоризму почала в'янути, і Карл Фішер уже не так часто і охоче повторював саме слово смерть: одна річ, коли він її насилає на міста і села, і зовсім інша справа, коли вона чатує на тебе, як на цих асів, що за якусь хвилину перетворились на купу безформного м'яса і кісток… // Михайло Стельмах, «Велика рідня», 1951.
- і «[одне діло](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac6&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%22[%D0%9E%D0%BE]%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%22+%22%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%22) <…>, а інше <…>»:

  > Адже ж одне діло приятелювати з таємничим і привабливим своєю загадковою надзвичайністю комашиним татом, і цілком інше — з людиною, подібною до пупса. // Віктор Петров-Домонтович, «Доктор Серафікус», 1929.

Comment: Можливо є сенс відсортувати згідно кількості траплянь в ГРАКу? Це було б логічно.

Comment: @Yola, річ у тім, що результати пошуку, на які я посилаюся, — це результати пошуку «одна справа»/«одна річ»/«одне діло», а не «одна справа <…>, інша <…>»/«одна річ <…>, інша <…>»/«одне діло <…>, інше <…>». Я наразі не знаю, як у «ГРАКу» зробити точніший запрос; і вручну лічити теж не хочеться. (Окрім того, є ще варіанти, наприклад, хтось пише «друга» замість «інша», або комбінує «одна справа <…>, інше діло <…>», абощо.)

Comment: Так, але не маючи іншої інформації, логічно виходити з того, що того чого більше знайшло навіть в такому форматі того і більше. Якщо ж є якась додаткова інформація, яка змушує надати перевагу саме такому сортування, то її варто надати.

Comment: @Yola, там переважна більшість траплянь у стилі «мені треба завершити одне діло», тому не думаю, що кількість про щось каже. Я ніякому варіанту не мав на увазі надавати перевагу (відсортував просто за абеткою зворотно). (Мені особисто найбільше подобається середній.)